# How do I navigate onion to get into the dark web?

Tags: onion-routing

It just goes to the home screen every time. I can’t figure out how to even get into the dark web. I downloaded TOR and onion from the App Store since I am using an iPhone but can’t figure out how to get past the home screens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use Tor browser on my iphone without jail breaking it?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1893/how-can-i-use-tor-browser-on-my-iphone-without-jail-breaking-it)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an official Tor app for iOS but the Tor Project recommends Onion Browser.

https://blog.torproject.org/tor-heart-onion-browser-and-more-ios-tor